# The function SUM cannot work with value of type string Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

% of Total Etsy Products = DIVIDE(SUM('categorycount_table'[categorycount]),100)

Trying to divide but getting below issue -

The function SUM cannot work with a value of type string.

Below is the structure of categorycount_table.

Note - This table is created from two different table.

| Date | categorycount |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| 01/01/2012 | 12121 |
| 01/02/2012 | 1231 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**
the column currently is in text format, you should change it into number format.

**Solution:**

- firstly change data type into number format under [column tools] in Powerbi view;
  [image]
- if no change then you need go to PowerQuery to check if there are any text values in this column. remove these text values (usually N/A, no data, or errors) then change data type.
  [image]

**Further information:**

- when the column is in text format, values would be in left side.
  [image: text format]
- when the column is in number format, values would be in right side.
  [image: number format]

Answer (score 1):

In data view, make sure the data type for 'categorycount_table'[categorycount] is a number.

[image]